How can I get the system time to display accurately in the output pdf? YAML Sys.time no longer working?
I'm doing what is suggested in this post: YAML current date in rmarkdown as it is the only other one I could find, and I'm just getting the verbatim code in the title page of the latex document instead of the actual system time.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.
I tried removing the / in front of the quotes but then I get an unexpected token error.
How can I get the system time to display accurately in the output pdf?
yaml <- "
---
title: 'Grade Report'
author: 'John Smith'
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), \"%d %B, %Y\")`'
output:
  pdf_document: 
---
\\pagenumbering{gobble}
"

latex_code <- ''
for (i in 1:n) {
  latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, "\n\n\\pagebreak\n")
  currentname <- df2[1, paste("Student", i, sep = " ")]
  currentreport <- df2[df2[paste("Student", i, sep = " ")] == 1, c(1, 2, 3)]
  
  if (sum(!is.na(currentreport$Points)) == 0) {
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, '\n')  
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, "\\begin{center}\n\\section*{", title, "}\n\\end{center}\n") 
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, "\\begin{center}\n\\textbf{\\large Name: ", currentname, "}\n\\end{center}\n") 
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, "\\begin{center}\n\\textbf{\\large Grade: 100 }\n\\end{center}\n") 
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, '\n\n')  
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, '&nbsp;')
    currentreport <- data.frame(Question = "-", Description = "-", Points = "-")
  } else {
    deduct <- sum(currentreport$Points)
    grade <- 100 + deduct
    
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, '\n')  
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, "\\begin{center}\n\\section*{", title, "}\n\\end{center}\n") 
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, "\\begin{center}\n\\textbf{\\large Name: ", currentname, "}\n\\end{center}\n") 
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, "\\begin{center}\n\\textbf{\\large Grade: ", grade, "}\n\\end{center}\n") 
    latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, '\n\n')  
    
    currentreport[nrow(currentreport) + 1, ] <- list(NA, "Total points deducted", deduct)   
    currentreport[nrow(currentreport) + 1, ] <- list(NA, "Grade", grade)
  }
  
  table <- xtable(currentreport, align = "lclc")
  latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, print(table, hline.after = c(-1, 0, nrow(currentreport) - 2, nrow(currentreport)), 
                                        comment = FALSE, include.rownames = FALSE, digits = 0, size = 'large'))
  latex_code <- paste0(latex_code, '\n') 
}

latex_document <- paste(yaml, latex_code, collapse = '\n')

latex_file <- "output_table.tex"
writeLines(latex_document, latex_file)

render(latex_file)



Try removing the backslashes. If yo have single quotes outside you can have unescaped double quotes inside.

The entire yaml is in double quotes though.  So I can't use the double quotes again.

Save your input file with extension .Rmd not .tex. Only when the extension of the file is .Rmd (or .rmarkdown or .qmd) will the file (and all R chunks) processed via knitr. see https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/835335d955a560efee04019ae60f586731bcf35c/R/render.R#L349
